# Registry hive question

Tags: c++, c, registry

Does anyone have a smal example of how to programmatically, in c/c++, load a users registry hive?  I would loike to load a hive set some values and close the hive.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Tony

Comment: What do you mean "load a users registry hive"? From a file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't got a specific example, but the Windows API calls you need would be:

- `RegOpenKeyEx()` to load the registry
  key
- `RegSetValueEx()` / `RegGetValue()` [and sister
  functions] to get/set registry values
- `RegCloseKey()` to close the
  registry.

There's some example code [behind this link on codersource.net](http://www.codersource.net/win32_registry_operations_2.html) ... although I can't vouch for how complete or correct it is. Review against the MSDN :-)

Comment: I know of those functions and have used them many times before, but how do I load a users hive?  Maybe I am missing something with those functions, so I will look again.  I do not remember anything about loading a specific hive for a user.

Answer (score 3):

You can use RegLoadKey() and RegUnLoadKey().  You can build the paths to the user hives (NTUSER.DAT) via the HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList.  However, it's generally not a good idea to use these functions willy-nilly.  If the user tries to logon while you have his profile loaded, he will be unable to load his profile and will get a temporary default profile.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724895(VS.85).aspx) you should pass predefined key HKEY_CURRENT_USER as first argument of RegOpenKeyEx function.
You can also [enumerate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724256(VS.85).aspx) HKEY_CURRENT_USER passing it directly to RegQueryInfoKey.